# Manipular Listas em Python com uma fórmula matemática

Tags: python

Tenho que fazer um determinado calculo com números reais gerados aleatoriamente em pyton. No meu caso, serão 10 números gerados aleatoriamente, e após isso, preciso que cada número da minha lista, seja inserido na minha fórmula para que o cálculo seja efetuado.
A fórmula é: mínimo + (máximo - mínimo)* x
onde x é cada número gerado aleatoriamente na minha lista

até agora fiz assim:

```py
minimo = 50
maximo = 130

numrandomicos = [random.uniform(0,1) for r in range(10)]
print(numrandomicos)
```

Comment: Já estou laços de repetição? Se sim, basta você fazer um laço que percorre a sua lista aplicando a fórmula desejada sobre cada valor.

Comment: usei um laço com for, ficou assim: for numero in numrandomicos:
    numeros = minimo+(maximo-minimo)*numrandomicos
    print(numeros)

Comment: E não é isso que precisa fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Você possui uma sequência de valores e deseja gerar outro valor a partir desses. Isso é uma relação injetora 1:1, ou seja, para cada valor da entrada você gera um valor na saída. Esse processo é denominado mapeamento e pode ser implementado em Python com a função `map`:

```
resultado = map(lambda x: minimo + (maximo - minimo)*x, numrandomicos)
```

A expressão *lambda* neste caso implementará a função que deseja aplicar sobre os valores.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```py
for numero in range(10):
    numrandomicos = random.uniform(0,1)
    numero = minimo+(maximo-minimo)*numrandomicos
    print(numero)
```